# What issue is there, when training this network with gradient descent?

Tags: gradient-descent, backpropagation, perceptron

Suppose we have the following fully connected network made of perceptrons with a sign function as the activation unit, what issue arises, when trying to train this network with gradient descent?
[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "what issue arises"? Have you encountered issues when training such a network already?

Comment: @Oxbowerce This is an exercise from a past exam, which suggests that there is an issue. I have not used a network of this type for an actual tasks/ encountered an issue myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what issue arises, when trying to train this network with gradient descent?

The activation function is *sign function or signum function* [(*A little modified*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function).

So, its Derivative will be 0 at all the points

 *Hence, the Gradient descent won’t be able to make progress in updating the weights and backpropagation will fail.*